# onNotification handler cordova-fcm-plugin-with-dependecy-updated

Tags: vue.js, cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have implemented push notifications using the `cordova-fcm-plugin-with-dependecy-updated` package in my vue-cordova app. Now I want to do some additional handling when a push notification is received (when the app is not in foreground). This should be done using the `onNotification(data)` handler, but I don't know where this handler should be placed.

When I put the code in `main.js` (root-level) the app doesn't even start, but showing a white screen right after the splashscreen.

```js
FCM.onNotification((data) => {
  cordova.plugins.notification.badge.increase();
  if (data.wasTapped) {
    //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});
```

Where should the handler be placed in my code, or which additional imports do I need?